# How to disable a tkinter OptionMenu

Tags: python, unix, tkinter, optionmenu

I can't figure out or find how to disable a tkinter OptionsMenu. I have 3 optionsmenu's in my GUI and want to disable them when a button is clicked

```
self.menu = OptionMenu(self, var, *items)
btn = Button(self, text="disable", command = self.disable)
btn,pack()

self.disable(self):
    //Disable menu here...
```

Is there a way to just call a built in function for OptionMenu and disable it? Or do I have to disable every option in the menu? (Which i also can't figure out)

BTW: I used the `menu.pack()` for a separate Topleve() window that pops up, but I started off with the grid() system in my main Tk window, used  by `menu.grid(row=0,column=0)`

> **EDIT:**
>   So I forgot to mention that I have multiple OptionMenus being generated by a constructor method. This is what I tried doing and didn't work:

```
makeMenu():
    menu = OptionMenu(self, var, *items)
    ....//whole bunch of menu settings
    return menu

menu1 = makeMenu()
all_menus.append(menu)
```

Now the reason this didn't work is because I had to append it after creation. I don't know why the settings don't carry over, but what I had to do is this:
    makeMenu():
        menu = OptionMenu(self, var, *items)
        ....//whole bunch of menu settings
        return menu

```
makeMenu():
    menu = OptionMenu(self, var, *items)
    ....//whole bunch of menu settings
    all_menus.append(menu)

makeMenu()
```

And with this change, I can use this to disable menus later on:

```
for menu in all_menus:
   menu.config(state=DISABLED)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I disable all the user input widgets (buttons,entries..) from a parent widget?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22382746/how-do-i-disable-all-the-user-input-widgets-buttons-entries-from-a-parent-wi)

Comment: Close. But this has to do with OptionMenu's which work a little differently. I used that question for my input entries. It works! But unfortunately it doesn't with OptionMenu's. Thanks for the heads up though!

Comment: I tested it and it does work on OptionMenus. Admittedly there's no optical clue, but if you click a disabled OptionMenu nothing happens.

Comment: Ok. I'll give it another shot. If it still doesn't work, i'll post my attempt as an edit above.

Comment: If that wasn't clear, the "parent widget" isn't the OptionMenu. An OptionMenu has no child widgets. I was thinking of your 3 OptionMenus as the children of some container.

Comment: It worked @Rawing!!!!!! Thank you!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Like with any other widget, you use the `configure` method to set the state to "disabled":

```
self.menu.configure(state="disabled")
```

The above will work for both the tkinter and ttk `OptionMenu` widgets.

Comment: On a side note, for some reason, the other state is called 'active' and not 'enabled' ‍♂️

Comment: @TheTomer: the valid states are active, normal, and disabled.